# "Driver needed by your ethernet card" Kali Linux on Early 2015 Macbook Air

Tags: linux, debian, macbook, kali-linux, macbook-air

I got an unexpected question when installing Kali Linux on my Late 2015 MacBook Air:

> Detect network hardware
>
> No Ethernet card was detected. If you know the name of the driver needed by your Ethernet cars, you can select it from the list.

The list is huge.

Some of the notable names are:

```
rtl8723ae: Realtek 8723e 802.11ax PCI wireless
b43legacy: Broadcom 4400 10/100 PCI Ethernet 
adm8211: Driver for IEEE 802.11b wireless cards based on ADMtek ADM8211
```

I would restart and try to find information in it, but the installation was failing before ( tried more than 10 times), and it is working now. I don't wanna take any chances.

What is the right driver?
Thanks!

Edit 1 : this is the only information I found in Apple's website :

> Wireless: 802.11ac Wi-Fi wireless networking; IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n compatible

Comment: I would guess it's brcmsmac or brcmfmac.

Comment: Let the install finish. Then you can use a command like `lspci -vnn | grep -i net` to find out what network hardware you have.

Comment: Turns out the driver isn't listed in there by default... Not in apt-get also. I will probably need to install something afterwards. I guess there is no good answer to this question.